# Scroll Bars in jQuery Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery menu which slides in from the left when clicked. I cannot seem to get a scroll bar to display on the side of the menu, it scrolls using a mouse wheel or trackpad. But it is not apparent to the user that there is content below what they can already see.

http://sohobarmontpellier.com/

Menu is on the left hand side.

I have already tried;

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
```

+

```
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 500px;
```

But neither of these display a scroll bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no problems seeing the scroll bar once i clicked the hamburger menu. Using V 46.0.2490.33 beta-m Google Chrome

Comment: Thanks, it seems 'overflow-y: scroll !important;' did work. But only on windows. OS X still displays no scroll bar. Very annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
overflow-y: scroll !important;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Already tried but unfortunately doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks, this actually did work but only for Windows. Not OS X.